# Flycheck UsePackage with C++11

Tags: c++11, emacs, flycheck

I use `use-package` for my emacs configuration.
Unfortunately I cannot properly configure the `flycheck` package to work with C++11 extension.

Here what I have so far:

```
;; == Flycheck ==
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :init
  (global-flycheck-mode)
  :config
  (setq flycheck-clang-language-standard "c++11"))
```

Although I set the proper variable, the `flycheck` gives me an error on *c++11* syntax (e.g. `auto i = 10`).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem once. I cannot test it right now (will do it later today) but what I finally did was adding a hook to c++-mode rather than setting `flycheck-clang-language-standard` variable.

Here is code from my init file.

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq flycheck-clang-language-standard "c++11")))
```

You can try to use it in your `use-package`.

**EDIT**

Okay, I just checked it. When in my init.el file I have only

```
(require 'flycheck)
(flycheck-mode)
(setq flycheck-clang-language-standard "c++11")
```

flycheck highlights `auto` variable in a cpp file and I can see in the minibuffer following information.

> rvalue references are a C++ extension

When I change my init.el file to

```
(require 'flycheck)
(flycheck-mode)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda () (setq flycheck-clang-language-standard "c++11")))
```

There is no error.